# Neural Networks in Matlab

Tags: neural-network, matlab

I'm having a problem using the neural network toolbox in matlab. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light.

I have two files training.csv and testing.csv, which hold the training and testing data, respectively. Using the neural network toolbox gui, I am able to upload the inputs (the training data), but no matter what it will not let me upload any target data.

Why? How do I fix this? I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, or if Matlab is going crazy.

edit 1: There is no error message. It simply ignores whatever I have clicked on, so everything looks the same before I tried to upload any data for the target data. And at the bottom, it just keeps telling me to select targets and then click Next.

edit 2: all my data is numerical, though the first column is used to give a positive (1) or negative (-1) classification to the example.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt see edit 1

Comment: Do you use `nftool`? Can you post your CSV?